# Enable TNT in certain areas only

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldguard

Is there any way you can enable TNT in certain regions in Minecraft (regions defined with WorldGuard) but disable it where it is not specifically allowed using WorldGuard? If not, are there any addons which can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can define a region with the wooden hatchet and then with worldguard flag the TNT to disallow it

```
 /region flag "region_name" tnt deny
```

Remove the " " for the region name that you gave.

Here's a list of things you can allow or deny for regions

http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Regions/Flags

**To disable TNT in the entire world**

Go to this place where the WG plugin's installed

```
plugins/WorldGuard/config.yml
```

And look for the line where it says

```
block-tnt
```

Set it to **true**

Comment: But how to disallow it for the whole world and then overwrite this?

Comment: @Andalur Added an answer for this

Comment: This does not work, when I try to ignite TNT in the region it does no damage even if I set flags properly.

Comment: @Andalur Did you disable ("deny") the TNT in the region, or enable ("allow") it? This answer is confusing, because both commands disable TNT. You have to pick one to reverse.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I disabled TNT with worldguard globally an then tried to enable it manually in a region using flags.

Comment: @Andalur you can't do this... you have to allow it globally and THEN you can disable it in certains areas